# Find Tab Name of Value of Cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheet where I'm trying to consolidate all of my data into one tab vs 57 tabs. I have the data I'm looking for all consolidated using the Query function, but is there a way to also tell which tab the data came from like Serial Number 1234 was on Order23 Tab? I like to make a link to that tab since it's a large document.

I tried looking at the =sheetName() option but that made it seem like it was specific to that one tab and I need something that populates the Tab Name based off of a value like Serial Number 1234 was on Tab13 or something.

Answer (score 0):

you can print it within query itself like:

```
=QUERY(Order23!A:B, "select A,B,'Order23' label 'Order23'''")
```

so your ultimate query will be:

```
=QUERY({
 QUERY(Order23!A:B, "select A,B,'Order23' label 'Order23'''");
 QUERY(Order23!A:B, "select A,B,'Order24' label 'Order24'''");
 QUERY(Order23!A:B, "select A,B,'Order25' label 'Order25'''");
 etc.}, "where 1=1")
```